# How to make this GET show the link url?

Tags: php

I have:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/machinima/uploads?fields=item(title,pubDate)&orderby=updated&alt=rss&client=ytapi-youtube-rss-redirect&v=2
```

I would like this to show the link element of the RSS feed too.

Adding `item(title,pubDate,link)` does not seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I would like this to only get title,pubDate,link and not the entire feed (for bandwith reasons), hence the problem.  Sorry if that was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to *replace* the `item(title,pubDate)` part directly after the `?fields=` key:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/machinima/uploads?fields=item(title,pubDate,link)&orderby=updated&alt=rss&client=ytapi-youtube-rss-redirect&v=2
--------------------------------------------------------------------^
```